# How to transform xml using xsl in dart

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xslt

I have searched on internet but I did not find any solution of my problem.Following code transform xml using xls in java but I need same functionality in dart.

```
      Transformer transformer = this.getTransformer(mContext);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(byteArrayOutputStream);
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlDocument)), xmlOutput);

        MessageDigest digest = null;
        byte[] hashSHA256 = null;

        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            hashSHA256 = digest.digest(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashSHA256);
        }else{
            return new String(
                    android.util.Base64.encode(hashSHA256, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
            );
        }
```

I tried xsltProcesser but it deprecated.

Comment: This has come up in the past with suggestions to try to use SaxonJS with the JavaScript integration packages/features that flutter and/or dart provide. But your  shown Java code seems to do two things, first run an XSLT transformation, then to create a signed base64 encoded hash of the transformation result. SaxonJS can do XSLT 3 transformation, for signing/hashing/base64 encoding you would need to look into other packages.

Comment: I had never used dart before yesterday, it seems you can use it to construct various types of apps, for a web app it appears you can access JavaScript libraries (like SaxonJS 2 is for XSLT 3) so I tried to build a prototype to see whether I could call SaxonJS within a dart web app; example gist is at https://gist.github.com/martin-honnen/df6f31214fd1a5907d1fa14eaa37b38d. I can't tell whether that is in any way helpful to answer your question as I have no idea so far how flutter uses dart. So this goes in a comment, if you find you can use the approach prototyped in the gist let me know.

Comment: I want to transform for android and ios not for web.